# Newtonsoft.Json returning '\' character

Tags: c#, json.net

I´m using Newtonsoft.Json library to serialize an object. The problem is that when I create the JSON string, it comes with '\' character. I´ve seen some answers that said that this is only a debugger issue, but I'm getting the JSON with this '\' up to the client that is consuming the service.
I also tried to remove this chacater with a function but it seems that it is happening the exact same with StringBuilder.

```
private static string DatatableToJSON(DataTable dt)
{
    string JSONresult;
    JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);
    return JSONresult;
}
```

And I´m getting:

> "[{\"Id\":\"72d209d5-0028-4162-94d0-d8cae856e1b7\",\"UserName\":\"nicolas\",\"Nombre\":\"ASD\"},{\"Id\":\"8ecdd5eb-b6a8-40f7-87a6-28ae39d5924c\",\"UserName\":\"mario\",\"Nombre\":\"ASD\"},{\"Id\":\"c48d2d27-40af-4bfe-a912-a18689c70076\",\"UserName\":\"diego\",\"Nombre\":\"ASD\"}]"

Can anyone help me with this?. It is driving me crazy!.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an escaping for a quote. Read more about chars escaping in C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: I have read a lot of information about it, but I could not find how to avoid getting that same character on client side

Comment: It can not appear on a client side. If it does - you did something wrong. SerializeObject returns a proper string without any backslash symbols. Backslash symbols appear during debugging or coding to distinguish them from string beginning \ end quotes. Can you post a code sample? Here is my code sample which works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tB6bbv

Comment: does the `/` break something?

Comment: Yes, It is just preventing me to parse the JSON correctly. The point is that that character should not be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this resolved my problem. I hope it helps someone:

```
public static IHtmlString SerializeObject(object value)
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            // Let's use camelCasing as is common practice in JavaScript
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        // We don't want quotes around object names
        jsonWriter.QuoteName = false;
        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);

        return new HtmlString(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a escape character.In `String`, you can see the backslash as escape characters.You can run that's code.

```
JSONresult.ToString();
```

The output didn't include **"\"**.

Comment: This is also returning the '\' character, I´ve just tested id

Answer (score 0):

Those are escape character. You could just replace all the `\'`,`\"`, `\\` to `'` ,`"` ,`\`.
Anyway, that is weird if they appear on the client side. I think it may be the string format or filter that you was using.